# ReactJS making a cross domain request using POST and GET fails with code 405

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, cross-domain

I am trying to make a cros request to skyscanner and get some information. I have studied their [doc](https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#flights-live-prices) and here is what I need to do:

1. make  a session using POST request,
2. then get a response header,
3. then use that url to make GET request,
4. to get flight data.

So basically there are 2 API calls.

This is the code I have:

```
export function getFlights() {

    const request = axios.post(
        'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/',  
        JSON.stringify({
            "cabinclass": "Economy",
            "country": "UK",
            "currency": "GBP",
            .
            .
            .
            .
            "apikey": "apikey"
        }), 
        {   
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.headers);
            axios.get(response.headers.location + '?apiKey=apikey&stops=0&duration=360&includeCarriers=ba;u2;af').then(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    return {
        type: GET_FLIGHT, 
        payload: request
    };
}
```

So I removed some of the query parameters and also hide the api key.

I have downloaded `allow-control-allow-origin` extension for chrome, and I have also changed the host file in: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, so now I am accessing my application through a test domain: `http://testdomain.com:3000/`

But when I try to get the result, I get the following error:

> POST http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/ 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

When I go to `NETWORK TAB` and I select `XHR`, I see `v1.0/ partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing` which is red and under the `headers` I can see:

> General 
>   Response Headers 
>   Request Headers 
>   Form Data, which has (seems like) a flight with my parameters??

I am not sure what I have done wrong but from the documentation and everything else seems like I should be getting code 200 which is for success but I keep getting 405. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, after loading the `querystring` library:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

var data = {
    cabinclass: 'Economy',
    country: 'UK',
    currency: 'GBP',
    // ...
    apikey: 'apikey' // be sure your API key is correct
};

var authOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0',
    data: querystring.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    json: true
};

axios(authOptions)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.status);

        axios.get(response.headers.location + '?apiKey=apikey&stops=0&duration=360&includeCarriers=ba;u2;af').then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
```

According to the [doc](https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#creating-the-session), try to use `http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0` instead of `http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/` (without **/**).

Comment: I changed my `return {
  type: FETCH_LOCALS, 
  payload: data
 };`,  but now it fails at `POST http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0 400 (Bad Request)`, in the preview part udner XHR, can see `ValidationErrors
:
[{ParameterName: "OutboundDate", ParameterValue: "2018-02-09'", Message: "Incorrect date format",…}]
0
:
{ParameterName: "OutboundDate", ParameterValue: "2018-02-09'", Message: "Incorrect date format",…}
Message
:
"Incorrect date format"
ParameterName
:
"OutboundDate"
ParameterValue
:
"2018-02-09'"
ValidFormat
:
"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Comment: do u know what is the problem now?

Comment: You have a problem in your date format for the `OutboundDate` parameter, you probably put `2018-02-09'` instead of `2018-02-09`, or something like that. Have a look? If it doesn't work, can you add all your parameters in your first post?

Comment: thnaks i think the pot part works now, it gives the code 201, but now I am getting `GET http://testdomain.com:3000/undefined?apiKey=apikey&stops=0&duration=360&includeCarriers=ba;u2;af 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You should receive a Location header with the following content: `Location "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk1/v1.0/
    {SessionKey}"`, what do you have?

Comment: i dont have that part, its confusing for me. I am not sure how to do it !

Comment: how can I get the sessionkey from the post?

Comment: I think this is an another question. But what is displayed (the response) in your console when you do the post request? Can you show me the `console.log(response.headers);` response?

Comment: that returns `response.headers: {content-type: "application/json", cache-control: "private"}` and `response.headers.location:  undefined`

Comment: Try this: `console.log(response);` instead of `console.log(response.headers);`. What do you get?

Comment: i am getting code 201`{data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: "Created", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164491/discussion-between-cusmar-and-s-n).