# GET error code 404 (Not Found)

Tags: get, http-headers, axios, es6-promise

Following my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607228/reactjs-making-a-cross-domain-request-using-post-and-get-fails-with-code-405), I am  getting

```
 XHR finished loading: POST  "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0".
```

seems the POST is working correctly, but for GET:

```
 GET
 http://testdomain.com:3000/undefined?apiKey=APIKEY&stops=0&duration=360&includeCarriers=ba;u2;af
 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (bundle.js:23687)
    at settle (bundle.js:23657)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (bundle.js:23529)
```

here is that part of the code:

```
axios(authOptions)
.then(function(response){
    console.log("response ====> ", response.headers);
    console.log("--->", response.headers.Location);
    /*
    console.log("data is: ", response.data);
    console.log("response.request.responseURL: ", response.request.responseURL );
    console.log("response headers", response.headers);
    console.log("location headers: ", response.headers.location);
    */
   var newAuthOpts = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: response.headers.Location + '?apiKey=APIKEY&stops=0&duration=360&includeCarriers=ba;u2;af',
        data: querystring.stringify(data),
        json: true
    };
    axios(newAuthOpts).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});

return {
    type: FETCH_LOCALS, 
    payload: data
};
```

I am trying to get the correct url from the header: `response.headers.location`, but this returns undefined, I can not find the error. can some one help please?

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between `response.headers.location` and `response.headers.Location` - *everything in JavaScript is case-sensitive*. In other words both versions could co-exist and be treated as completely different properties. It's for this reason that camelCase is commonly used. In that way we can easily recognise it as an error when, for example, a property begins with a capital letter.